# "bind EADDRINUSE null" errors in express application logged thousands of times

Tags: node.js, express

We have a small node express app with the following line in the app.js file:

```
app.listen(8080, () => console.log('listening on port 8080.'));
```

There are logs files in a .pm2 directory that are logging, over 2 weeks period of time, what seems to be millions of the following errors, all the same:

```
Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:8080
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at listenOnMasterHandle (net.js:1411:16)
    at rr (internal/cluster/child.js:111:12)
    at Worker.send (internal/cluster/child.js:78:7)
    at process.onInternalMessage (internal/cluster/utils.js:42:8)
    at emitTwo (events.js:131:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:772:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

It appears the "app.listen" is being invoked over and over again, but I did not think this was how express/node.js worked.

The log entries are milliseconds apart. This application has maybe 10-15 users in total, and the amount of errors is not commensurate with the amount user activity.

There are no other areas of the system where we are performing app.listen on that port.

What could be causing the "app.listen" code to fire so often, thus creating the error?

Comment: The error looks like the Address already in use. So some others will be running on 8080 port. PM2 will try to restart the application when it crashed and that why you have the same error multiple time. `pm2 status` will give you information on how many time the server restarted

Comment: Are you running in pm2 cluster mode? Are you trying to spawn multiple instances? That would match thousands of "address in use" errors since they'd all try to listen to 8080.

Comment: How can I tell if its running in cluster mode?

Comment: Express application was trying to listen on same port as another app.